# How return list of tuples in python when using dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to return values in the format:

```
[("CarB", 2000), ("CarA", 2002)]
```

This is how I'm generating my list of tuples:

```
car_tuple = list(tuple(CAR_DF[['name_car','year']].to_records(index=False)))
```

But the values in `car_tuple` are not converted as tuples.

Comment: It's the same. There's no difference between single quote and double quote in python.

Comment: If you change the single quotes in your code to double quotes it might change something.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was that `list(CAR_DF[['name_car','year']].to_records(index=False))`
don't return a list of tuples.

`print(type(car_tuple[0]))` returns `<class 'numpy.record'>`

and

`print(type(car_tuple[0]))` returns `<class 'numpy.int32'>`

In order to fix that, I've used:

```
CAR_DF_2 = CAR_DF[["name_car","year"]]
tup = [tuple(a) for a in CAR_DF_2.to_numpy()]
car_list_tuple = list(tup)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @psidom stated. You can get single quotes as follows

```
CAR_DF = pd.DataFrame({'name_car':['CarA','CarB'], 'year':[2000,2002]})



   name_car  year
0     CarA  2000
1     CarB  2002


s = [x for x in CAR_DF.agg(tuple,1)]

print(s)

[('CarA', 2000), ('CarB', 2002)]
```